# CLPlacemark.subThoroughfare strange characters?

Tags: objective-c, ios, geocoding

When logging out or sending (to a web service using RestKit) specifically the subThoroughfare property of CLPlacemark strange characters appear where I would expect a hyphen to be.

Logging:

```
NSLog(@"%@", placemark.subThoroughfare);
```

Results in:

```
12-
```

Where I would expect 12-15. The 15 is missing.

Also, when sending the subThoroughfare string to a JSON service I see the following in the request:

```
12â??15
```

The 15 is present, however the hyphen is replaced by strange characters.

Have not been able to find a solution via Google/SO, and any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
A fuller example of an address logged to the console is:

```
 Placemark Address: 34‚Äì36 Friars Way, Eaton, Engla
```

Note the last 2 characters are also missing (should read 'England'), when the ‚Äì replaces the hyphen (-). I am looking into encoding, however not getting far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the strange characters are due to the LLDB debugger not being able to show Unicode characters correctly...switching to GDB showed the characters correctly.